# Is Google de-anonymizing me?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security, vidalia, deanonymization, google

I am a regular TBB user. I update TBB as and when updates are available, with at most a delay of a few days. The bundled addons are also updated regularly. I also have the standalone Vidalia package installed & I usually run it along with TBB. Both are run from a USB Flash drive. I run TBB with NoScript set at "forbid scripts globally" and I use its "temporarily allow ..." option, ad hoc, per site, to gain the requisite functionality from the site.

I have noticed recently, while accessing google.com, that I was being redirected by Google to its country site where I am currently located. When I looked at the exit node it was in a different continent. I've observed that Google.com usually redirects to encrypted.google.com and sometimes to its country site where the exit node is located, when accessed through Tor. I'm not sure how to interpret the anomalous behavior of google.com. Should I assume that my real ip has been revealed to google.com and perhaps to other sites? Is any information being preserved across sessions in the form of cookies or some other means? I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.

Update: I have noted that the behavior seems to be occuring only for that particular exit-node.

Comment: Does the country match the language setting of your Tor Browser? If you're using the Italian bundle for example, Google might be detecting your language and redirecting you based on that.

Comment: Thank you. No, I don't think that's the case. I've always used the default en-us download. Besides, I've been using TBB for a fairly long time and this is the first time it has happened, as far as I know.

Comment: Dear Frasier, You are not logging to anything, are you?

Comment: The redirection to encrypted.google.com is probably HTTPS Everywhere doing its thing. The redirection to a country site is probably the location of the exit node or somebody else using the same exit node and a country specific google

Answer (score 1):

Try typing into Google, "What is my ip?" if it displays your real IP than your question is answered.  You may also want to clear all Cookies on  Mozzila FireFox, that may patch this issue.